# Akka-grpc: how to authenticate request?

Tags: authentication, akka, akka-http, akka-grpc

Is there a way to intercept request in akka-grpc? (I need to get authentication info and enrich request with it).

Comment: I know you are referring to akka-grpc, but still to give an idea take a look at this.
I coudn't find any doc in akka-grpc for it.
https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth.html#overview

Comment: https://github.com/akka/akka-grpc/issues/382